# Create a parser script with a delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, awk, delimiter, substitution

I am trying to convert this input from `file.txt`

```
a,b;c^d"e}
f;g,h!;i8j-
```

into this output

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

with awk

The best I did so far is

`awk '$1=$1'  FS="[!;^}8-]"   OFS=","   file.txt`

1. how can I escape interpritating `"` as a special character ?   `"` doesn`t work
2. avoid duplicate `,,`  in the output and delete the last `,`

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
a,b;c^d"e} f;g,h!;i8j-
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[a-z]";OFS=","}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is single lowercase ASCII letter using `FPAT`, and output field separator (`OFS`) is `,`, then for each line I do `$1=$1` to trigger line rebuild and `print` line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to replace non-letter characters with commas and squeeze repeated commas, `tr` is your friend:

```
tr -sc '[:alpha:]' ','
```

This will leave a trailing comma though. You could use `sed` to remove/replace it:

```
tr -sc '[:alpha:]' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Another possibility is to split each "item" into its own line (with `tr` or `grep -o`), then use `paste` to combine the lines again:

```
tr -sc '[:alpha:]' '\n' | paste -sd,
```

Comment: This would leave a lone comma as the last character. and it would lack a trailing newline. You could remove the last comma by piping into `head -c -1`, and then add the newline somehow (perhaps by wrapping it into a `echo` or `printf`).

Comment: @user1934428 good catch. I have adapted my answer, thanks

Comment: Great idea to use `paste`! Didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 2):

One in awk (not for all awks, tested successfully in gawk, mawk, busybox awk and Macos awk version 20200816, unsuccessfully in Debian's  awk version 20121220 aka original-awk. Limitations in locales as well.)

```
$ awk -v RS="^$" '{      # read whole file in 
    gsub(/[^a-z]+/,",")  # replace all non lowercase alphabet substrings with a comma
    sub(/,$/,"")         # remove trailing comma
}1' file                 # output
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

Comment: TIL that busybox awk and Macos awk version 20200816 support multi-char RS! I'm particularly shocked about the MacOS one since I use it fairly frequently and have been working around assuming it didn't support that!

Comment: Me too on the Macos but it happened to be next to my bed (battlestation for the holidays :).

Comment: Works on Debian wheezy, `mawk` 1.3.3-17

Comment: @GillesQuenot You are right, my bad. Mawk is the Debian default, not original-awk.

Answer (score 2):

Using any POSIX awk and assuming you want any non-alphabetic character to act as a field separator:

```
$ awk -F '[^[:alpha:]]+' -v OFS=',' '{printf "%s", p; $1=$1; p=$0} END{sub(OFS"$","",p); print p}' file
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

If you really do just want to use the specific set of characters in your question as the field separators then just change `[^[:alpha:]]+` to `[!;^}8"-]+`

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

The `script.ed`

```
%s/[^a-z]/ /g
%s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/,/g
g/./;j\
s/,$//
,p
Q
```

---

Now run

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

Answer (score 1):

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```
$ grep -o '[a-z]' file | paste -sd ',' -
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

Should works on most `GNU/Linux`, even `busybox` & `freeBSD` (the `-` is then mandatory)

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-sed` replace 1 or more chars other than a-z with a comma. Then remove all leading and trailing comma's

```
sed -Ez 's/[^a-z]+/,/g; s/^,+|,+$//' file
```

Output

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "${input_data}" |
```

> ```
> mawk 'NF-=_==$NF' FS='[^[:alpha:]]*' OFS=, RS=
> ```

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

if there's possibility of leading edge seps, use this instead :

```
echo ']a['
```

> ```
> gawk 'gsub("^,|,$",_,$!(NF=NF))^_' FS='[^[:alpha:]]*' OFS=, RS=
> ```

```
a
```

** side note : beware that `nawk` has an unconventional definition of what it considers `[[:alpha:]]` :

```
reparse <[[:alpha:]]+>

cclenter   : in = | . .. |, out = 
   
|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 ªµºÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞ
   ßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ|
```

Even though locale is set as `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`, `nawk`'s idea of `[[:alpha:]]` is neither `ASCII` nor full `Unicode` -

something resembling, but not necessarily identical, to a legacy 8-bit locale like `ISO-8859-...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with Perl solution, here is an one-liner;

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/[^[:alnum:]]//g; print join(",", split//, $_)'
```

which outputs:

```
a,b,c,d,ef,g,h,i,8,j
```

Simply, you are substituting characters that are not alpha-numeric with nothing.